# What do these words have in common, and where?

Tags: wordplay, language, geography

**What do the following have in common?**

> India, black, $10^{-6}$, many, south

(*More or less* the same process can be applied to all of them to get very similar and related results.)

Comment: I'm not sure $10^{-6}$ counts as a word unless it's meant to be "millionth". However, what counts as a word is up for [some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8niIHChc1Y) [debate](http://www.proz.com/forum/money_matters/104575-do_numbers_count_as_words.html).

Comment: @EngineerToast, „micro” could also work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Are they all places in the Pacific Ocean? If each word (or an appropriate variant) is used as a prefix for "esia", you get (*more or less*) the following:
>  India -> Indonesia (meaning Indian island)
>  Black -> Melanesia (*melan* is a prefix for dark or black)
>  $10^{-6}$ -> Micronesia (micro is the prefix for $10^{-6}$)
>  Many -> Polynesia (*poly* is a prefix for many)
>  South -> Austronesia (*austri* is Latin for south; thanks to the commenters for puzzling this one out!)

Comment: Very good! Try to do the same thing with "black" and "south" - it does work!

Comment: Melanesia for black, and Micronesia for 10^-6

Comment: Yeah, just got melanesia after looking up melan for melanin and other things! :D Still thinking about South (unless it's just South Asia, but I think I want more)!

Comment: What about Australasia which is Latin for 'South of Asia'? That would give you a list of regions within Oceania: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceania

Comment: There is no such region as Austronesia, but [Austronesian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Austronesian?q=austronesian) denotes a family of languages.

Comment: @Mark Good call, I didn't know "australis" was Latin for "southern" so I didn't see the link to Australasia. That seems close enough to match the "more or less" of the process!

Comment: @MOehm [Ahem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austronesia)

Comment: @randal'thor: Touché. The Online OED doesn't have it, though and I suppose it might be a back formation from Austronesian as family of languages. (I had to look it up, because I'd heard of the other Nesias, but not of this.)

Comment: @MOehm Me too, actually! :-) I came up with the other 4 first, and looked up to see if there was any other -nesia I could use. The "more or less" is just because some of the prefixes are Greek and others Latin.

Comment: I've updated the final clue! Thanks, all!

Answer (score 6):

They're all places (town names, with the exception of #5) within the Southern United States.

1. [India, Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India,_Texas)
2. [Black, Alabama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black,_Alabama)
3. [Micro, North Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro,_North_Carolina)
4. [Many, Louisiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many,_Louisiana)
5. [South(ern United States)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_United_States)

Comment: Nice find (though unintentional). But you've converted $10^-6$ to "micro" while leaving the rest the same, and the last one is a bit of a cheat! The intended answer works better than this :-)

Comment: There are a couple of places in the US named "South", in [Kentucky](http://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=gnispq:3:::NO::P3_FID:503891) and [Alabama](http://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=gnispq:3:::NO::P3_FID:127111).